# Verify route possibility MapKit

Tags: objective-c, routes, mapkit

How do I verify if it's possible to the user go from his current local to a destination x through automobile transport? When the user choose a destination in my application that is not possible to arrive by car, it's just dont do nothing, and i want to display a warning to the user that is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used `calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler` method from `MKDirections` to discover it. Here's what i did

```
__block BOOL existRoute = nil;

    [directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if(response.routes.count > 0){
            existRoute = YES;
        }else{
            existRoute = NO;
        }

    }];
```